# TestFlight Beta app status on device after 30 day test period

Tags: testflight

In TestFlight what happens to the Beta app on testers' devices after the 30 day test period?  Is it automatically uninstalled?  Does it remain on the device? If we upload a new build before the 30 day period ends will it replace the previous build?

Answer (score 0):

It will stay on the device, but will not start anymore. It also cannot be installed again.

If you upload a new build, it will be installed on top of the old one.

Comment: Thanks. We have also discovered that the data created by the previous build is still available after the build expires and is replaced after the expiration period.  Now we wonder if the app data will be available to the user if an app released publically through the iTunes store with the same Build number is installed on the device with the previous Beta installed.  Anyone experience that?